# Should I normalize my data in Google AppEngine Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the next Models in AppEngine :

```
class Category(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.StringProperty()

class Blog(db.Model, Handler) :
    subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    last_modified = db.DateProperty(auto_now = True)
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(Category, required=True)
```

Is this a correct approach Normalize my data or not?

Comment: FWIW, the `db` solution is superceeded, you may want to use `nbd` instead. See note on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/api-overview. Also - it's unclear what you're asking - what do you mean by normalize the data?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly – you should do exactly the opposite thing since this is NoSQL database. You make writes expensive (by duplicating data in many entities) but reads will be extremely cheap then. Of course, it's depends on the application. Not a good question for stackoverflow anyway.